# Picasso load drawable resources from their URI

Tags: android, picasso

I have to show a `drawable` from `res` into an `ImageView`. In this app, I'm using Picasso for some reasons.

In this case, I need to load the `drawable` using its URI and not its id.
To do that, here is my code:

```
uri = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://"+context.getPackageName()+"/drawable/" + drawableName);
```

where drawableName used here are file names rather than their resource ids.

Then

```
Picasso.with(context).load(uri).into(imageView);
```

I know for sure that drawable name is correct, but Picasso seems it does not like this uri.

Comment: you cannot "load" anyrhing into drawable folder, resources are read only

Comment: Sorry my english is not so good :)

Comment: its not your english, its good enough, i meant that you cannot add anything into drawable folder

Comment: No no I'm not load anything  into drawable folder. I'm loading a drawable into an ImageView using Picasso.

Comment: ok, so where is the image you want ro show? in your app res/drawable?

Comment: yep I've put a png inside the drawable folder

Comment: https://github.com/square/picasso/pull/292

Comment: You can put images in drawable or mipmap. Generally drawable folder is good for keeping xml for shapes, selectors and backgrounds. You can also put 9 patch images in drawable folder. A 9 patch will not be recognised from the mipmap folders. mipmap folder is strictly for the images. This way you categorise, organise and keep from mixing your image resources.

Comment: Answer is just above this name: https://www.journaldev.com/13759/android-picasso-tutorial#android-picasso-8211-loading-image-from-file

Comment: replace .with(context) with .get.. i.e.Picasso.get().load(uri).into(imageView);

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found the answer. Unfortunately, Picasso do not allow drawable loading via URI. It is an incoming feature.

Comment: Is this still like that?

Comment: Picasso now support using URI. Refer this https://square.github.io/picasso/javadoc/com/squareup/picasso/Picasso.html

Comment: but you have to use picasso jar v2.5 to use that feature

Comment: @Fahim, the link has moved, however: Lots of examples can be find at: https://www.journaldev.com/13759/android-picasso-tutorial#android-picasso-8211-loading-image-from-file

Answer (score 88):

If the images is in your drawable folder then you can just load it.

```
Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.drawableName).into(imageView);
```

and picasso will load it no need for an Uri.

Comment: I need dynamic reference to the drowables

Comment: For dynamic reference use:

int resId = this.ctx.getResources().getIdentifier("<package_name>:drawable/" + imageName, null, null);

Comment: Will not work for vector drawable, at least for now, July 30, 2018

Answer (score 9):

- *This is if you don't want to hardcode the image that you are going
  to load...*

You can load local image files from your drawable folder lazily if you know the integer value of the image that you want to be loaded.

Then you can just do:

```
Picasso.with(getContext()).load(imageResourceId)
.error(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
.into(imageView);
```

Where

> imageView

is the view you wish to display the image. For example:

```
imageView = (ImageView) convertView
.findViewById(R.id.itemImage);
```

And where

> imageResourceId

is the integer value of the drawable. You can retrieve this integer value by:

```
int productImageId = resources.getIdentifier(
productImageName, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
```

as well as

> productImageName

is the name of the drawable you want to draw (i.e. "ic_launcher")

THIS CAN ALL BE DONE INSIDE FROM THE **ADAPTER**

Comment: You can put images in drawable or mipmap. Generally drawable folder is good for keeping xml for shapes, selectors and backgrounds. You can also put 9 patch images in drawable folder. A 9 patch will not be recognised from the mipmap folders. mipmap folder is strictly for the images. This way you categorise, organise and keep from mixing your image resources.

Comment: Answer is just above this name: https://www.journaldev.com/13759/android-picasso-tutorial#android-picasso-8211-loading-image-from-file

Comment: with() method is deprecated now, use Picasso.get().load(imageResourceId).into(imageView)

Answer (score 8):

From [picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) v2+ here is a big modification. The new version is very helpful in order to manage image cache data. It's using Singleton Instance.

**GRADLE**

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

**Set drawable image**

```
Picasso.get()
    .load(url)
    .placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder)
    .error(R.drawable.user_placeholder_error)
    .into(imageView);
```

**Bonus, get drawable by name:**

```
public static int getDrawableIdFromFileName(Context context, String nameOfDrawable) {
        return context.getResources().getIdentifier(nameOfDrawable, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
}
```

Comment: It's drawable id. You can get it with his method getDrawableIdFromFileName()

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in the documentation of [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/javadoc/com/squareup/picasso/Picasso.html) .

they are now supporting loading Image from URI like the following :

```
load(android.net.Uri uri)
```

so you have to do something like the following :

```
Picasso.with(context).load(uri).into(imageView);
```

just like what you are doing already .

Hopethat helps .

Comment: ok what about this ? http://square.github.io/picasso/javadoc/com/squareup/picasso/Picasso.html#load(android.net.Uri)

Comment: That method works for every URIs except the ones whose point to an internal resource (such as a drawable). Ie: `Uri.parse("http://website.com/image.jpg")` is a valid URI for Picasso. But Picasso is not able to load a drawable with `Uri.parse("android.resource://your_drawable")`. As they said, this feature will be available for Picasso 2.2+

Comment: Leave it.. there could be other people with your same doubt :)