# Picasso don't load images from drawable (Android)

Tags: android, picasso

i have a problem with picasso library.

I have a Navigation Drawer with a View Pager, and in View Pager i load images from drawable folder.

I have an array of strings like this

```
public static final String [] IMAGES = 
{
        "drawable://" + R.drawable.aa12, 
        "drawable://" + R.drawable.acr, 
        "drawable://" + R.drawable.ai_l96a1,
        etc.
}
```

and this is how I try to load images:

```
Picasso.with(mContext).load(Constants.IMAGES[position]).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_stub).into(imageView);
```

the problem is that in my ViewPager it shows me only the *ic_stub* image.

Did somebody know why ?

Comment: Why do you use strings to identify the drawables? Is it working if you use an Array of ints and just put the Drawable ids in there?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21163826/1576416

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using a integer array

```
    int[] image_array = new int[] { R.drawable.aa12, R.drawable.acr,
            R.drawable.ai_l96a1, etc };
```

And load using

```
Picasso.with(mContext).load(image_array[position]).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_stub).into(imageView);
```