# Picasso library does not load Images from URI

Tags: android, picasso

I am using Picasso in a list adapter to load images asynchronously from URIs

```
Picasso.with(viewHolder.albumArt.getContext())
.load(songObject.albumArtURI)
.placeholder(R.drawable.grayalbumart)
.into(viewHolder.albumArt);
```

The problem is that the images aren't being loaded. I only see the placeholder images.

**note: I am not loading URLs. I am loading URIs.**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21158425/picasso-load-drawable-resources-from-their-uri?rq=1
check this link

Comment: which version of Picasso are you using ?

Comment: provide the String url not a URI of the Image.

Comment: @the_prole first check u can got the image url from "songObject.albumArtURI" & also check actually what u can pass? like File ,String URL Etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered my own question

```
if(songObject.albumArtURI != null){

        File f = new File(songObject.albumArtURI);

        Picasso.with(viewHolder.albumArt.getContext())
                .load(f)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.grayalbumart)
                .into(viewHolder.albumArt);
    } else {

        Picasso.with(viewHolder.albumArt.getContext())
                .load(songObject.albumArtURI)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.grayalbumart)
                .into(viewHolder.albumArt);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use callbacks to know whether bitmap from your image is correctly loaded into your imageview.

you can use picasso's callback as below

```
Picasso.with(getContext())
    .load(url)
    .into(imageView, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                          // Log something here eg "true"
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {
                         // Log something here eg "false"
                    }
                });
```

Now if your bitmap is correctly loaded then true will be logged or else false. if its true then do not worry, it its false then check whether your url is correct or not.

**Note:- make sure in the url which your receive from server, there are no spaces in file name otherwise it wont load, I myself have faced this issues many time, so just cross check for the names you receive.**

Answer (score 0):

IF it is from drawable folder then:

```
uri = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://"+context.getPackageName()+"/drawable/" + drawableName);

Picasso.with(viewHolder.albumArt.getContext())
.load(uri)
.placeholder(R.drawable.grayalbumart)
.into(viewHolder.albumArt);
```

Comment: Not using drawables. I'm using URIs. Anyways, I answered my own question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

I have added this code to my adapter

```
        String url = alist.get(position).getProfileImage();

        holder.ivPic.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(holder.ivPic);
```

Comment: what if url is null ?

Comment: it will display display_pic image in your image view.