# OutofMemory Error in frame animation

Tags: android, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, android-bitmap, animationdrawable

I have developed a tour guide app. Some of the classes have frame animation. 3 activities with frame animation work well. But if another similar activity is clicked, it gives the memory leak error. 
Images are loaded from Drawables folder. Whole drawable folder contains 3.58 MB. I can't understand why it's giving this error. Please help with this. Thanks in advance.

This is my logcat.

> > 08-18 10:45:14.585: E/dalvikvm-heap(9523): Out of memory on a
> >     6444816-byte allocation.
> >
> > prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE 08-18 10:45:14.585: I/dalvikvm(9523):   |
> >     group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x41e46578 self=0x41cc9938 08-18
> >     10:45:14.585: I/dalvikvm(9523):   | sysTid=9523 nice=-16 sched=0/0
> >     cgrp=apps handle=1074774012 08-18 10:45:14.585: I/dalvikvm(9523):   |
> >     state=R schedstat=( 4068370710 523035518 4253 ) utm=308 stm=98 core=0
> >
> > 08-18 10:45:14.585: I/dalvikvm(9523):   at
> >     android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method) 
> >     android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:596)
> >
> > 08-18 10:45:14.585: I/dalvikvm(9523):   at
> >     android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
> >
> > 08-18 10:45:14.585: I/dalvikvm(9523):   at
> >     android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:832)
> >
> > 08-18 10:45:14.585: I/dalvikvm(9523):   at
> >     android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2988) 
> >     android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602) 08-18
> >
> > android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:131) 08-18
> >
> > android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:121) 08-18
> >
> > java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 08-18
> >
> > java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 08-18
> >
> > android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600) 08-18
> >     10:45:14.585: I/dalvikvm(9523):   at
> >     com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
> >     08-18 10:45:14.585: I/dalvikvm(9523):   at
> >     android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
> >
> > android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
> >
> > android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 08-18
> >
> > android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 08-18
> >
> > android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 08-18
> >
> > android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 08-18
> >
> > android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 08-18
> >
> > com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:361)
> >     08-18 10:45:14.585: I/dalvikvm(9523):   at
> >
> > D/AndroidRuntime(9523): Shutting down VM 08-18 10:45:14.590:
> >     W/dalvikvm(9523): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception
> >     (group=0x41e45700) 08-18 10:45:14.595: E/AndroidRuntime(9523): FATAL
> >     EXCEPTION: main 08-18 10:45:14.595: E/AndroidRuntime(9523):
> >     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> >     ComponentInfo{com.isuru.allaboutkataragama/com.isuru.allaboutkataragama.Kabiliththa_Dewalaya}:
> >     android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #53: Error
> >     inflating class  08-18 10:45:14.595: E/AndroidRuntime(9523):
> >
> > com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
> >
> > android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
> >         at
> >     android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
> >     at
> >     android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 08-18
> >         at
> >     android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 08-18
> >         at
> >     android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 08-18
> >         at
> >     android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 08-18
> >         at
> >     android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 08-18
> >         at
> >     com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:361)
> >         at
> >     android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1956) 08-18
> >         at
> >     com.isuru.allaboutkataragama.Kabiliththa_Dewalaya.onCreate(Kabiliththa_Dewalaya.java:57)
> >         at
> >     android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372) 08-18
> >         at
> >     android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
> >         at
> >     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
> >
> > 10:45:14.595: E/AndroidRuntime(9523): Caused by:
> >     java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 08-18 10:45:14.595:
> >     E/AndroidRuntime(9523):     at
> >     java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 08-18
> >     at
> >     java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 08-18
> >         at
> >     android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600) 08-18
> >
> > E/AndroidRuntime(9523): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError 08-18
> >
> > android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method) 08-18
> >
> > android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:596)
> >
> > android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
> >
> > android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:832)
> >
> > android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2988) 08-18
> >
> > android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602) 08-18
> >
> > android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:131) 08-18
> >
> > android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:121)

This is my code

```
public class Kabiliththa_Dewalaya extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener{

    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    ArrayList<LatLng> mMarkerPoints;
    double mLatitude=0;
    double mLongitude=0;
    ImageView iv1,iv2,iv3;
    Button contact_kebiliththa;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.kebiliththa);

         BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.imageView1_kabiliththa, options);
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.imageView1_kebiMap, options);
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.imageView1_kabiliththa2, options);
            int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
            int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
            String imageType = options.outMimeType;

            iv1.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.id.imageView1_kabiliththa, 100, 100));
            iv2.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.id.imageView1_kebiMap, 100, 100));
            iv2.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.id.imageView1_kabiliththa2, 100, 100));
            contact_kebiliththa=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button_contactKebiliththa);
            contact_kebiliththa.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+"0773539292"));
                    startActivity(callIntent);

                }
            });

        // Getting Google Play availability status
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

        if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ // Google Play Services are not available

            int requestCode = 10;
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
            dialog.show();

        }else { // Google Play Services are available

            // Initializing 
            mMarkerPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

            // Getting reference to SupportMapFragment of the activity_main
            SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_kabiliththa);

            // Getting Map for the SupportMapFragment
            mGoogleMap = fm.getMap();
            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(new LatLng(
                    6.418266, 81.324671)).zoom(8).build();

            mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

            double Kabiliththalatitude =6.513917;
            double Kabiliththalongitude =81.691930;

            final LatLng Kabiliththa=new LatLng(Kabiliththalatitude, Kabiliththalongitude );
            Marker Kabiliththa_marker=mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("Kabiliththa Dewalaya").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE)).position(Kabiliththa));
            Kabiliththa_marker.showInfoWindow();

            // Enable MyLocation Button in the Map
            mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);


            // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

            // Getting the name of the best provider
            String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

            // Getting Current Location From GPS
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

            if(location!=null){
                onLocationChanged(location);
            }

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);           

          mGoogleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker m) {
                mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(m.getPosition(), 17));
                m.remove();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Tap again in the location",
                           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                // Setting onclick event listener for the map
                mGoogleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {

                        // Already map contain destination location 
                        if(mMarkerPoints.size()>1){

                            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();   
                            mMarkerPoints.clear();
                            mGoogleMap.clear();
                            LatLng startPoint = new LatLng(mLatitude, mLongitude);
                            drawMarker(startPoint);
                        }

                        drawMarker(point);

                        // Checks, whether start and end locations are captured
                        if(mMarkerPoints.size() >= 2){                  
                            LatLng origin = mMarkerPoints.get(0);
                            LatLng dest = mMarkerPoints.get(1);

                            // Getting URL to the Google Directions API
                            String url = getDirectionsUrl(origin, dest);                

                            DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

                            // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
                            downloadTask.execute(url);
                        }                   
                    }
                });     

                return false;
            }
        });


        }       
    }

    private String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin,LatLng dest){

        // Origin of route
        String str_origin = "origin="+origin.latitude+","+origin.longitude;

        // Destination of route
        String str_dest = "destination="+dest.latitude+","+dest.longitude;          

        // Sensor enabled
        String sensor = "sensor=false";         

        // Building the parameters to the web service
        String parameters = str_origin+"&"+str_dest+"&"+sensor;

        // Output format
        String output = "json";

        // Building the url to the web service
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"+output+"?"+parameters;      

        return url;
    }

    /** A method to download json data from url */
    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try{
                URL url = new URL(strUrl);

                // Creating an http connection to communicate with url 
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                // Connecting to url 
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Reading data from url 
                iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

                StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();

                String line = "";
                while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
                        sb.append(line);
                }

                data = sb.toString();

                br.close();

        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
        }finally{
                iStream.close();
                urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return data;
     }



    /** A class to download data from Google Directions URL */
    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{         

        // Downloading data in non-ui thread
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

            // For storing data from web service
            String data = "";

            try{
                // Fetching the data from web service
                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
            }
            return data;        
        }

        // Executes in UI thread, after the execution of
        // doInBackground()
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {           
            super.onPostExecute(result);            

            ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

            // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
            parserTask.execute(result);

        }       
    }

    /** A class to parse the Google Directions in JSON format */
    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> >{

        // Parsing the data in non-ui thread        
        @Override
        protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

            JSONObject jObject; 
            List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;                     

            try{
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
                DirectionsJSONParser parser = new DirectionsJSONParser();

                // Starts parsing data
                routes = parser.parse(jObject);    
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return routes;
        }

        // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
            ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
            PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;

            // Traversing through all the routes
            for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
                points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
                lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

                // Fetching i-th route
                List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

                // Fetching all the points in i-th route
                for(int j=0;j<path.size();j++){
                    HashMap<String,String> point = path.get(j);                 

                    double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                    double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                    LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng); 

                    points.add(position);                       
                }

                // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
                lineOptions.addAll(points);
                lineOptions.width(6);
                lineOptions.color(Color.RED);   

            }

            // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
            mGoogleMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);                            
        }           
    }   



    private void drawMarker(LatLng point){
        mMarkerPoints.add(point);

        // Creating MarkerOptions
        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();

        // Setting the position of the marker
        options.position(point);

        /** 
         * For the start location, the color of marker is GREEN and
         * for the end location, the color of marker is RED.
         */
        if(mMarkerPoints.size()==1){
            options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
        }else if(mMarkerPoints.size()==2){
            options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
        }

        // Add new marker to the Google Map Android API V2
        mGoogleMap.addMarker(options);      
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // Draw the marker, if destination location is not set
        if(mMarkerPoints.size() < 2){

            mLatitude = location.getLatitude();
            mLongitude = location.getLongitude();
            LatLng point = new LatLng(mLatitude, mLongitude);

            mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(point));
            mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(8));        

            drawMarker(point);          
        } 

    }

    public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and width
        final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
        final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

        // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will guarantee
        // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
        // requested height and width.
        inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}

    public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
            int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
    }


    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }


}
```

My xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/RootView" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_kebilithta"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="65dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/Kebiliththa_header"
            android:textColor="#000033"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1_kabiliththa"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/imageVw"
            android:src="@drawable/kabi5" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_kebilithta1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="122dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/Kebiliththa_description1"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_kebilithta2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/Kebiliththa_decrip2"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1_kabiliththa2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/imageVw"
            android:src="@drawable/kabi1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_kebilithta4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="99dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/Kebiliththa_descrip4"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1_kebiMap"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/imageVw"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/kebiliththa_map" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_kebilithta41"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="12dp"
            android:text="@string/Kebiliththa_troute_1_header"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_kebilithta42"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:text="@string/Kebiliththa_route1"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_kebilithta43"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="13dp"
            android:text="@string/Kebiliththa_troute_2_header"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_kebilithta44"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:text="@string/Kebiliththa_route2"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_kebilithta45"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="13dp"
            android:text="@string/Kebiliththa_troute_3_header"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_kebilithta46"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:text="@string/Kebiliththa_route3"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="12dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView_contactKabi"
                android:layout_width="54dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/imageVw"
                android:paddingTop="6dp"
                android:src="@drawable/phone" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_contactKebiliththa"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#000033"
                android:text="@string/Kebiliththa_tours"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_dire"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="25dp"
            android:text="@string/getDirections1"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_markerDire"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="@string/markerTap"
            android:textColor="#FF0000" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map_kabiliththa"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="470dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

ANimation List

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

     <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/kiri2"
        android:duration="10000"/>

     <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/kiri10"
        android:duration="8500"/>

     <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/kiriwehera8"
        android:duration="8500"/>


    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/kiri9"
        android:duration="8500"/>

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/kiriwehera5"
        android:duration="8500"/>

      <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/kiriwehera6"
        android:duration="8500"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/kiriwehera7"
        android:duration="9000"/>

</animation-list>
```

Comment: what is density of your images, size and format....?

Comment: Format is jpeg.
sizes
960 x 720, 457 x 304 , 1600 x 1007, 960 x 720

Comment: you are not using large image efficiently...please go through this...http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200256/out-of-memory-error-imageview-issue

Comment: try this 
change iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animation_kiriwehera);
to iv.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.animation_kiriwehera));

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable comments. I edited the code (Class File). But now I'm getting a nullPointer Exception. Some uncaught exception. 
COuld you please refer the code.