# setImageResource and memory leak

Tags: android, performance, android-memory

In my Activity, I use `imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_name);` about 8 times for different views.

**I kept opening and closing the activity repeatedly** and I notice the app is getting laggy. I am wondering if this is related to memory leak? Is it because of that piece of code?

Comment: now should be the time to start using `MAT` and checking what is still in memory

Comment: Totally a opinion based question. What are your findings ? did you use any Memory Analysis tool ? like MAT or so ? how big is your image ? what resolution is your image? how much device memory has ? what is the heap size ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should `recycle()` all your bitmaps when done using them. If you want to destroy them when activity is `finish()`ed, you can override `onDestroy` to destroy all bitmaps

Comment: setImageResource is counted as Bitmaps?

Comment: It should be of type `BitmapDrawable`. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/8306683/4795214

Comment: How do I recycle the bitmap if I use setImageResource in the first place? Thanks

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/13415604/4795214