# Glide is not releasing memory when using Databinding rules

Tags: android, performance, data-binding, memory-leaks, android-glide

I'm using fragments in a ViewPager, each page is having imageviews. I'm following databinding rules and i load image using Glide in BindingUtils. Now issue is that when i call Glide.clearMemory()  in onDestroyView of fragment. It doesn't clear memory and heap keeps on growing.

BindingUtils:

```
@BindingAdapter("imageUrl")
    public static void setImageUrl(ImageView imageView, String url) {
        Context context = imageView.getContext();
        if (url != null) {
            Glide.with(context).load(url).load(url))
                    .into(imageView);
   }
    }
```

From Fragment:

```
@Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        if (getContext() != null)
            Glide.get(getContext()).clearMemory();
        super.onDestroyView();
    }
```

I checked a [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42670237/5110536) answer at stackoverflow, and it states that imageView.getContext(); gives application context and when we release memory from fragment then it has fragment context. So, question is that how can i get the related context and release the memory then?  Any ideas would be appreciable.

Comment: hi did you solve the problem ?

Comment: I had to remove dataBinding in that case. Glide call was sent from the fragment/activity by passing the same context that we use to clear the request.

Comment: So  `Glide.get(getContext()).clearMemory();` is not working isn't it? Because I'm also using this exactly but it seem It doesn't reduce memory usage.

Comment: yes, it didn't see working when i was on that task.