# Android: is it ok to set the same bitmap to two ImageViews?

Tags: android, bitmap

Is re-using a single bitmap object for two `ImageView`s acceptable?

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
if (bitmap != null) {
    itemImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    itemImageView2.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

Comment: Remember to recycle the bitmap! Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200256/out-of-memory-error-imageview-issue/18197453#18197453).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah that's fine, you'll also want to recycle the bitmap when you're done.

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
if (bitmap != null) {
    itemImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    itemImageView2.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
bitmap.recycle();
```